Why this code fails to run successfully from imported module even though it runs very well when this entire code is run from the same page
I am trying to test my module by importing from my local directory. This code works flawlessly when instance is created  and a function call is made from the same page (without importing). However, when I move the code block to a module and import it, it keeps returnning error as shown below:
Following code is from my locally stored module named Admin.py:
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, last, age, nationality):
        self.name = name
        self.last = last
        self.age = age
        self.nationality = nationality
        
    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"\nAdmin name is {self.name.title()}, last name is {self.last.title()}, age is {self.age} and is of {self.nationality.title()} nationality\n")
        
    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"\nHello! {self.name.title()}, welcome to the XYZ Consultancy Services Ltd.\n")
        
class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privileges):
        self.privileges = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
            print("Privileges of the admin are:\n")
            for privilege in self.privileges:
                print(f"- {privilege}")

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, name, last, age, nationality):
        super().__init__(name, last, age, nationality)
        self.privileges = Privileges(privileges)

privileges = ["can add post", "can delete post", "can ban user"]


Following codes are from the page where I try to import the code block from my local module Admin.py and try to execute it.
from user import Admin


priv = Admin("veronica", "smith", 26, 'American')

priv.greet_user()

priv.describe_user()

priv.privileges.show_privileges()


Following is the returned output (error):
   92 #         super().__init__(name, last, age, nationality)
     93 #         self.privileges = Privileges(privileges)
     95 privileges = ["can add post", "can delete post", "can ban user"]
---> 97 priv = Admin("veronica", "smith", 26, 'American')
     99 priv.describe_user()
    101 priv.privileges.show_privileges()

   25 def __init__(self, name, last, age, nationality):
     26     super().__init__(name, last, age, nationality)
---> 27     self.privileges = Privileges()

TypeError: Privileges.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'privileges'


When this entire code is run from the same page, I get the following which is expected by me:
Hello! Veronica, welcome to the XYZ Consultancy Services Ltd.


Admin name is Veronica, last name is Smith, age is 26 and is of American nationality

Privileges of the admin are:

- can add post

- can delete post

- can ban user


I have tried almost every possible permutation/combination to fix this positional argument error but I have not been able to resolve it even after 6 hours of work.

Well I just tested this and it works correctly. But I notice that your import statement is from user import Admin, whereas mine is from Admin import Admin.

You don't import from user the list priviledges ... check the logic ... best provide the list items directly in the class Admin: self.privileges = Privileges(["can add post", "can delete post", "can ban user"]). Does it solve your problem?

I have found the reason. The privileges need to be added as an attribute to def init(self, foo, foo, foo, foo, privileges) method. I deleted the privileges list from the module file and moved it to my working file. Now I can create and use an update function to update my privilege list anytime I want without modifying the module file. No more renaming of the module files.

Notice that your answer is not an answer to your question, because you didn't asked for a solution like this ... You have asked for the reason why your code fails, and not for a suggestion of a better design of your project ...

Outcomes
After testing your Snippet in Conditions

Same File

Works Perfectly


Different File



Works Perfectly If,

Here, filename is user.py

from user import Admin


If trying from Admin.py

from Admin import Admin



Other Ways for Workarounds !

Using the globals() to list the global variables


External Reference : Click Here

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, name, last, age, nationality):
        super().__init__(name, last, age, nationality)
        self.privileges = Privileges(globals()['privileges'])

privileges = ["can add post", "can delete post", "can ban user"]

This will list globals() and reference them to use it.
I hope this answer help you in any way,Thank you..

I have found a better option. Just added privileges as an attribute to def init(self, foo, foo, foo, foo, privileges). I deleted the privileges list from the module file and moved it to my working file. Now I can use update function to update my privilege list any time I want.

Your problem is here:
privileges = ["can add post", "can delete post", "can ban user"]

You define this list in the file but not inside any class. Such connection modules doesn't provide. I would probably pack this options list inside Privileges if I were you.
Something like this should work fine:
class Privileges:
def __init__(self, privileges = []):
    self.privileges = privileges

def show_privileges(self):
        print("Privileges of the admin are:\n")
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print(f"- {privilege}")

Also you should somehow pack privileges options inside greet_user().
If this solution not fit for your preference at least move privileges options inside some class to make it a class field. If so you could access it and use as a module functionality.
(It's my first answer, please correct me if I somewhere was wrong.)

If you import Admin or from Admin import Admin you get the entire file imported, and privileges is then accessible. I don't know why OP is using from user ....

@Momentow, it is a better practice to use an immutable object as default value for example None. Other than that is a viable solution.

As mentioned above, I had errored by not adding the privileges as an attribute to the Admin class's init function. Once added, moved the privileges list back to my working file, and the issue was resolved. No changing of module file name or using any global variables.

The code you provide as an example works. The difference between that and the code that gave the TypeError is likely the absence of providing privileges to the call self.privileges = Privileges(privileges). You can see from the error message that the call is different self.privileges = Privileges().
A small note, in your question you refer to the file as 'Admin' however in your example you use 'user'.

The user is my parent class whereas the admin is its child class. I had named the file after the parent class. Important is that I should have declared privileges as a global variable.
